# Is a hibernation partition primary?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, hibernate

The Lenovo X1 Carbon comes with the hard-drive split into what appears to be 4 partitions:

1. Windows (C:)
2. Recovery (Q:)
3. SYSTEM_DRV
4. Hibernation

In *Disk Management*, under *Status*, all but the hibernation (4) are marked as primary. However, in the diagram below, they are all colored blue and the legend says that blue means primary. So which is it? Here is the screenshot:

[image]

**Is the hibernaton partition a primary one?** Does that mean I am out of partitions? Or does the four primary partition limit no longer apply? If it still applies some times, how can one check?

Comment: What does `Disk Manager` say?  There isn't enough information to tell you.  If you post a screenshot of Disk Manager we could.

Comment: @Ramhound - Sure. Here it is. I thought my description was sufficient, sorry.

Comment: Yes; Its going to be a primary partition;  I assume this is an MBR partition instead of GPT?  Your description was good.  There is an old saying "a picture is worth a thousand words" hence my request.